# Cannot be resolved to type - Android

Tags: android

So I get this error saying "xy cannot be resolved to type" and "the method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) of type KalandActivity must override or implement a supertype method" the code was written on another computer and worked well on that one. I imported it and got a lot of problems. I tried some solutions I found online, but nothing seemed to help. There are other classes which have problems too. Could someone give some advice?

```
package hu.treasurefinder;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.R;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class KalandActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kaland);

    TextView cim = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cimView);
    final ImageView kep = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.kepView);
    TextView szoveg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.szovegView);
    Intent param = getIntent();
    Kaland kaland = (Kaland)param.getSerializableExtra("kaland");
    cim.setText("2");
    cim.setText(kaland.getNev());
    szoveg.setText(kaland.getLeiras());
    AsyncTask<String,Void,byte[]> task = new AsyncTask<String,Void,byte[]>() {

        @Override
        protected byte[] doInBackground(String... kep) {
            URL url;
            try {
                url = new URL("http://www.programozas-oktatas.hu/kaland/"+kep[0]);
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int readBytes;
                while ((readBytes = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    baos.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                }
                is.close();
                return baos.toByteArray();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(byte[] result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(result, 0, result.length);
            Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, kep.getWidth(), kep.getHeight(), true);
            kep.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);
        }

    };
    task.execute(kaland.getKep());
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.kaland, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: Where are the errors occurring?

Comment: Oh srry, I dont know how to mark errors. At super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); TextView cim = (TextView)          findViewById(R.id.cimView);
        final ImageView kep = (ImageView)                findViewById(R.id.kepView);
        TextView szoveg = (TextView)                      findViewById(R.id.szovegView);

Comment: Are you targeting the correct android version?